# Build object tree of already summed and grouped dataresult

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I currently want to do some optimization, so I used a manual SQL Query (without linq), which groups and sum a lot of data for me. This is the result I get:

```
+----------+--------+------------+
| Location | Client |   Amount   |
+----------+--------+------------+
| Foo      | Foo1   | 2850180,00 |
| Foo      | Foo2   | -173103,50 |
| Foo      | Foo3   |  595316,73 |
| Bar      | Bar1   |   -5264,80 |
| Bar      | Bar2   |   -2884,30 |
+----------+--------+------------+
```

I basicly obtain the data using `_ctx.Database.SqlQuery<MyStrongResultModel>(query).ToList()`

I now want to create an object tree from it.

```
public LocationInfo
{
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ClientInfo> ClientInfoCollection {get; set; }
}

public ClientInfo
{
    public string Client { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
data.GroupBy(e => e.Location).Select(locationGroup = new LocationInfo {
    Location = locationGroup.Key,
    ClientInfoCollection = locationGroup.GroupBy(e => e.Client).Select(clientGroup => new ClientInfo
    {
        Client = clientGroup.Key,
        Amount = clientGroup.Sum(e => e.Amount) //<-- Actualy this is only one record
    })
});
```

This works but seems like a wrong aproach, since my data already is grouped and summed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the data is already grouped and summed, then use simple `Select` instead of an inner `GroupBy`:

```
data.GroupBy(e => e.Location).Select(locationGroup = new LocationInfo {
    Location = locationGroup.Key,
    ClientInfoCollection = locationGroup.Select(e => new ClientInfo
    {
        Client = e.Client,
        Amount = e.Amount
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Totaly missed my coffee today :D